# Multiple tables for similar data in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am writing a server using Netty and MySQL(with JDBC connector/J).

Please note that I am very new to server programming.

Say I have an application that users input about 20 information about themselves.
And I need to make some methods where I need only specific data from those information.

```
Instead of using "select dataOne, dataTwo from tableOne where userNum=1~1000"
create a new table called tableTwo containing only dataOne and dataTwo.
Then use "select * from tableTwo where userNum=1~1000"
```

Is this a good practice when I make tables for every method I need?
If not, what can be a better practice?

Comment: No, absolutely not. The related information belongs in _one_ table.  `SELECT *` should not usually be used in production code, and it is recommended always to be explicit about the columns you need. Don't design your tables based on how you plan for your application to access them - design your tables based on how the data is related.

Comment: Additional(and irrelevent) question: are there any website or book that contain some good cases or practices in databases(escpecially MySQL)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be replicating data.

SQL is made in such a way that you specify the exact columns you want after the `SELECT` statement.

There is no overhead to selecting specific columns, and this is the way SQL is designed for.

There ***is*** overhead to replicating your data, and storing in 2 different tables.

**Consequences of using such a design:**

- In a world where we used only `select *` we would need a different table for each combination of columns we want in results.
- Consequently, we would be storing the same data repeatedly. If you needed 10 different column combinations, this would be 10X your data.
- Finally, data manipulation statements (`update`, `insert`)  would need to update the same data in multiple tables also multiplying the time needed to perform basic operations.
- It would cause databases to not be scalable.